# does the area under the curve (AUC) has some interpretation?

Tags: roc, measurement-error, model-evaluation

I know that the ROC curve plots true positives vs false positives, but does it have any other interpretation, or is it just an arbitrary performance measure? Also, in the case of very unbalanced response variable's classes (say 10 to 1) is an AUC of 0.5 still a bad thing?